# How to verify logon user in LDAP (Active Directory) on PHP - only one autentication?

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

Sorry fom my english...

Scenario:

I have user which is autenticated to the domain. User - windows XP -> Server - Windows 2008 Server Std. - Domain functionality is 2003.
User name user is in attribute sAMAccountName.

I have database in MYSQL and Apache server. I link to it with PHP page in browser.
I can link to LDAP database and read atributes from it.

Problem:
I would like to user to open page in browser was authenticated in LDAP.
Is in LDAP atrribute that user is autenticated?
I dont want that user use another time yours password.